# Zurb Foundation multi-column grid height issue

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Iv'e using Zurb Foundation like a pretty platform for fast develop light projects. And today i've stucked on one thing.
I don't know how to better call it, easer to show...

http://oi61.tinypic.com/2dkhfuq.jpg

So, it happens when above column have too much content.
Also... columns must have non-fixed height and don't use block-grid! TY!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to interpret what you're asking for. The first is that you're having a floating issue and the columns are stacking to the right. If you want the white space gone, you'll need a JS plugin like Masonry or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

The other way to interpret this is that you want these to be at the same height. There are 2 ways to go about this with Foundation: Either wrap each row with:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns"></div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns"></div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns"></div>
</div>
```

The row class basically runs a clear once it starts so it will give them space. You don't need to use my syntax but it would be a working example. If you want to have all the articles be the same height based on the biggest one, Foundation has a great plugin built in called [Equalizer](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html).

Equalizer and my column syntax rely on using Foundation 5.

Comment: Thank for your tips! For me th easiest way is equalizer, but it don't support multiline. With your example all works fine, but in future my code works with wordpress, and this code makes harder to create template for CMS. In the loop every 3 posts add row :D... If u understand me. So any way, thx for ur tip. I've found some information how to use masonry with zurb: http://patterntap.com/code/stacking-columns-layout-masonry      Sorry for my english:D

Comment: I'm also a Wordpress developer. You'll just need to create a counter that fires off every third one to create rows. I've done the same situation when placing ads inside of loops.

Comment: Ok, ty, mate. In this situation the best solution is create a wordpress loop. BUT! Somewhere i have equalizer that supports multiline, but i can't find :( Ty, again, mate. Good luck!:)

Comment: Got a simple solition! Equalizer that supports multiline: https://yadi.sk/d/FqW7hatLchTSH